# How to trigger a call to url when a machine is detected twilio

Tags: twilio

We are currently using Twilio's rest api to initiate calls. We want to use Twilios machine detection but are having issues. We want to fire off to a url no matter what the result and use the AnsweredBy to add some logic to return different twiml depending on whether it was answered by a human or machine.

we developing in C# and have the following code:

var call = CallResource.Create(
            to,
            from,
            url: successfulCallUrl,
            record: true,
            machineDetection: "Enable"
           );

but our url is only triggered if the call is answered by a human and not if it goes to an answer machine. we need it to be triggered no matter what the result of the call to determine what to do with it.

Comment: That is how the Answering Machine detection should work, so it's likely we can't fix this in Stack Overflow. I recommend you contact the [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) team and provide them with some Call SIDs for calls that did not trigger the webhook.

Comment: You request the same url no matter who answers (human or machine) inside the url handler you have to determine what to do with the call. Twilio sends an extra parameter along 'anweredBy' when machineDetection is enabled. Read that parameter inside your url handler and determine what to do with the call.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is requested when an outbound call is answered no matter what, the only difference is that if answering machine detection is on then an extra request parameter is supplied by Twilio. There is no scenario (as far as I'm aware) where Twilio will not request TwiML from your URL when a REST initiated outgoing call is answered.

What shows up as the request parameters in the request inspector for your voice logs? For calls answered by a human does Twilio supply an AnsweredBy parameter?

I just tried using the curl example on the Twilio site and let the call go to voicemail, in my console logs Twilio is posting to my call handling URL to retrieve my twiml with the following parameter, so what you want to do is technically possible.

> AnsweredBy    machine_start

Perhaps the answering machines you are calling are confusing Twilio and you need to reduce the timeout threshold? Maybe the C# syntax for enabling detection is different to yours? I don't know the answer, but your call logs will certainly yield a clue as to where to start.